# October CMS - Cannot edit pages in backend - http status 403

Tags: octobercms

After uploading my October CMS code base to the a cpanel based linux server, I can't edit my pages from backend (CMS->pages).

It gives me a popup with an http status code of 403 error page.

How can I fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known issue of the following: [Hosting limitations - cannot edit pages in back-end](https://octobercms.com/support/article/ke-1)

I've fixed the issue by adding the following block of config in my .htaccess  file:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off  
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get needed permission to access them. 403 error code is for 'forbidden access'. please check your granted permissions to you in server OS.

Comment: No this is not the issue here. Because the file system permission is not the issue here. Because, permissions are set to 775 or 777